# Identifying an inverse of a suspected Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a new operation of addition in Z which is defined as x ⊕ y = x + y -1.
I am trying to prove that it is a group and have shown closure and associativity hold.

> For the identity I have :
>
> > x+y-1+e = 0
> >
> > > therefore e = 1-x-y

Maybe I am overthinking this but would the inverse be the same as the identity?

Comment: I have another operation defined as: x ⊕ y = x + y -xy, and following your hint I have found e ⊕ x = e + x - ex = x. Therefore e = 0? So then x + y = xy for the inverse, but that is not always true obviously so this operation does not contain inverses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If there were an identity it would have to be an element so that $e \oplus x=x$ for all $x \in G$. This means that $e+x-1=x$, which is equivalent to $e=1$.

For the inverse of $x$, note that $x \oplus y=e=1$, or in other words, $x+y-1=1$.

Comment: Meija:  come on, show us the  inverse with respect to $\oplus$ so I don't have to do it.  ***Endorsed!!!***  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis if you insist :).

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Sooas integers, $y = 2 -x$.. Would you not agree? ;)